# React (fullpage.js) Web Application works in chrome & firefox but not in safari browser

Tags: reactjs, web, safari, frontend, fullpage.js

I'm building a test website (https://test.collegemate.app/), it's working on Chrome and Firefox but when I try to open the website in Safari, the scroll (fullpage.js) does not works at all. I try to debug using safari inspector, but not specific error message I notice.

This is my first web development project so this is the first time I encounter this type of issue. Please help me with this issue.

Thank you for your time!

Here is the code that related to the scroll function in webpage.

IndexWrapper.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck
import * as React from 'react';
import { Fullpage, Slide, HorizontalSlider } from 'fullpage-react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faChevronRight,
  faChevronLeft,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Pages
import FirstPage from './FirstPage';
import Feature from './Features';
import About from './About';
import LastPage from './LastPage';
import FooterModal from './Modal/FooterModal';
import FoundingTeam from './About/FoundingTeam';
const { changeFullpageSlide, changeHorizontalSlide } = Fullpage;

interface FeaturesData {
  title: string;
  comment: string;
  image: string;
}

/**
 * IndexWrapper class component.
 */
class IndexWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: {
        Fullpage: 0,
        features: 0,
      },
      isAboutModalOpen: false,
      isFooterModalOpen: false, // For Footermodal open Handling
      isService: true, // For tracking Footer modal information
    };

    this.onSlideChangeStart = this.onSlideChangeStart.bind(this);
    this.onSlideChangeEnd = this.onSlideChangeEnd.bind(this);
    this.setIsAboutModalOpen = this.setIsAboutModalOpen.bind(this);
    this.setIsFooterModalOpen = this.setIsFooterModalOpen.bind(this);
    this.setIsService = this.setIsService.bind(this);
  }

  /**
   * Handle the slide change start event.
   * @param {string} name - The name of the slide.
   * @param {object} props - The props object.
   * @param {object} state - The state object.
   * @param {object} newState - The new state object.
   */
  onSlideChangeStart(name, props, state, newState) {
    if (!this.horizontalNav) {
      this.horizontalNav = document.getElementById('horizontal-nav');
    }

    if (name === 'features') {
      scrollNavStart(this.horizontalNav);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handle the slide change end event.
   * @param {string} name - The name of the slide.
   * @param {object} props - The props object.
   * @param {object} state - The state object.
   * @param {object} newState - The new state object.
   */
  onSlideChangeEnd(name, props, state, newState) {
    if (name === 'features') {
      scrollNavEnd(this.horizontalNav);
    }

    const oldActive = this.state.active;
    const sliderState = {
      [name]: newState.activeSlide,
    };

    const updatedState = Object.assign(oldActive, sliderState);
    this.setState(updatedState);
  }

  setIsAboutModalOpen(boo0) {
    this.setState({ isAboutModalOpen: boo0 });
  }

  setIsFooterModalOpen(boo1) {
    this.setState({ isFooterModalOpen: boo1 });
  }

  setIsService(boo2) {
    this.setState({ isService: boo2 });
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;

    const currentActive = active.Fullpage;
    const goSlide1 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 0);
    const goSlide2 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 1);
    const goSlide3 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 2);
    const goSlide4 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 3);

    const horizontalSliderName = 'features';
    const horizontalActive = this.state.active[horizontalSliderName];
    // const horizontalActive = this.state.features;

    const prevHorizontalSlide = changeHorizontalSlide.bind(
      null,
      horizontalSliderName,
      horizontalActive - 1
    );
    const nextHorizontalSlide = changeHorizontalSlide.bind(
      null,
      horizontalSliderName,
      horizontalActive + 1
    );

    // Properly retrieve data and edit Feature component
    // TODO: Seperate Data from Code (Use Gatsby's GraphQL)
    const data = [
      {
        title: 'Customize Schedule',
        comment:
          "Customize your schedule effortlessly with CollegeMate - real-time data from UW's" +
          ' database at your fingertips. CollegeMate updates for you.',
        image: 'thumbnail_Feature1.png',
      },
      {
        title: 'Share Schedule With Friends',
        comment:
          'Eliminate the "What\'s your schedule?" dilemma. CollegeMate simplifies viewing friends\' ' +
          'timetables. No back-and-forth. Stay connected in a snap.',
        image: 'thumbnail_Feature2.png',
      },
      {
        title: 'Set Schedule as Wallpaper',
        comment:
          "Download your timetable to perfectly fit your phone's screen. Say goodbye to screenshots." +
          ' Access your schedule whenever and wherever.',
        image: 'thumbnail_Feature3.png',
      },
    ];

    const featureSlides = data.map((feature: FeaturesData) => (
      <Slide>
        <Feature data={feature} />
      </Slide>
    ));

    const horizontalSliderProps = {
      name: 'features',
      infinite: true,
    };

    horizontalSliderProps.slides = featureSlides;
    const fullpageOptions = {
      scrollSensitivity: 5,
      touchSensitivity: 5,
      scrollSpeed: 500,
      hideScrollBars: true,
      scrollOverflow: true,
      resetSlides: true,
    };

    const isAboutModalOpen = this.state.isAboutModalOpen;
    const isFooterModalOpen = this.state.isFooterModalOpen;
    const isService = this.state.isService;
    const modalInfo = { isFooterModalOpen, isService };

    return (
      <>
        {isAboutModalOpen && (
          <div
            style={{
              zIndex: 20,
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '200%',
              height: '100vh',
              width: '100vw',
            }}
          >
            <FoundingTeam setIsAboutModalOpen={this.setIsAboutModalOpen} />
          </div>
        )}
        {isFooterModalOpen && (
          <div
            style={{
              zIndex: 20,
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '300%',
              height: '100vh',
              width: '100vw',
            }}
          >
            <FooterModal
              data={modalInfo}
              setIsFooterModalOpen={this.setIsFooterModalOpen}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        {/* ^ open modal when isFooterModalOpen is true. Give data and function that are needed for opening modal with proper information */}
        <Fullpage
          onSlideChangeStart={this.onSlideChangeStart}
          onSlideChangeEnd={this.onSlideChangeEnd}
          {...fullpageOptions}
          slides={[
            <Slide>
              <FirstPage />
            </Slide>,
            <HorizontalSlider {...horizontalSliderProps}>
              <div id="horizontal-nav" style={horizontalNavStyle}>
                <Div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      height: '7vh',
                      width: '53px',
                    }}
                  >
                    {horizontalActive == 0 ? (
                      <span onClick={prevHorizontalSlide} style={hidden}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          icon={faChevronLeft}
                          size="5x"
                          style={horizontalArrowStyle}
                        />
                      </span>
                    ) : (
                      <span onClick={prevHorizontalSlide}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          icon={faChevronLeft}
                          size="5x"
                          style={horizontalArrowStyle}
                        />
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <EmptyBox />
                  </div>

                  <div
                    style={{
                      height: '7vh',
                      width: '53px',
                    }}
                  >
                    {horizontalActive == 2 ? (
                      <span style={hidden} onClick={nextHorizontalSlide}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          icon={faChevronRight}
                          size="5x"
                          style={horizontalArrowStyle}
                        />
                      </span>
                    ) : (
                      <span
                        // style={{ position: 'absolute', right: '0' }}
                        onClick={nextHorizontalSlide}
                      >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                          icon={faChevronRight}
                          size="5x"
                          style={horizontalArrowStyle}
                        />
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </Div>{' '}
              </div>
            </HorizontalSlider>,
            <Slide>
              <About setIsAboutModalOpen={this.setIsAboutModalOpen} />
            </Slide>,
            <Slide>
              <LastPage
                data={modalInfo}
                setIsFooterModalOpen={this.setIsFooterModalOpen}
                setIsService={this.setIsService}
              />
            </Slide>,
          ]}
        >
          <div style={slideNavStyle}>
            <ul>
              <span onClick={goSlide1}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 0 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>
              <span onClick={goSlide2}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 1 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>

              <span onClick={goSlide3}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 2 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>

              <span onClick={goSlide4}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 3 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </Fullpage>
      </>
    );
  }
}

/**
 *
 * @param nav
 */
function scrollNavStart(nav) {
  // make the nav fixed when we start scrolling horizontally
  nav.style.position = 'fixed';
}

/**
 *
 * @param nav
 */
function scrollNavEnd(nav) {
  // make the nav absolute when scroll finishes
  nav.style.position = 'absolute';
}

const slideNavStyle = {
  listStyleType: 'none',
  zIndex: 15,
  position: 'fixed',
  right: '3%',
  top: '40%',
  margin: 'auto',
  display: 'block',

  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },

  liStyle: {
    listStyleType: 'none',
    margin: '4vh',
  },

  circle1: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '2vh',
    width: '2vh',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    marginRight: '-20px',
    display: 'block',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease',
    backgroundColor: '#DEE3E5',
  },

  circle2: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '2vh',
    width: '2vh',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    marginRight: '-20px',
    display: 'block',
    transition: 'all 0.3s ease',
    backgroundColor: '#B20000',
  },
};

const horizontalArrowStyle = {
  height: '7vh',
  width: '53px',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  color: '#DEE3E5',
  transition: 'linear all 0.3s',
};

const horizontalNavStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '100vw',
  height: '50vh',
  display: 'flex',
  top: '25vh',
  zIndex: 14,
};

const EmptyBox = styled.div`
  width: 70vw;
  height: 7vh;

  /* Thin Mobile */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    width: calc(100vw - 106px);
  }

  /* Tablet */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1223px) {
    width: calc(100vw - 150px);
  }

  /* Mobile Landscape */
  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-height: 768px) {
    top: 40vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 130px);
  }
`;

const Div = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;

  /* Tablet */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1223px) {
    top: 40vh;
  }

  /* Mobile */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    top: 40vh;
  }

  /* Thin Mobile */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    top: 40vh;
  }

  /* Mobile Landscape */
  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-height: 768px) {
    top: 40vh;
  }
`;

const hidden = {
  opacity: 0,
  display: 'none',
  color: '#DEE3E5',
  transition: 'linear all 0.3s',
};

export default IndexWrapper;
```

I am suspecting that there is some issue in the code below (which is part of the code above) since it is related to the four buttons on the right side of the website.

```
  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;

    const currentActive = active.Fullpage;
    const goSlide1 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 0);
    const goSlide2 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 1);
    const goSlide3 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 2);
    const goSlide4 = changeFullpageSlide.bind(null, 3);
```

````
type           <div style={slideNavStyle}>
            <ul>
              <span onClick={goSlide1}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 0 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>
              <span onClick={goSlide2}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 1 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>

              <span onClick={goSlide3}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 2 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>

              <span onClick={goSlide4}>
                <li style={slideNavStyle.liStyle}>
                  {currentActive == 3 ? (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle2} />
                  ) : (
                    <label style={slideNavStyle.circle1} />
                  )}
                </li>
              </span>
            </ul>
          </div>```
````

Comment: Can you provide an isolated reproduction with the less amount of code in codesandbox or codepen?
I can't seem to reproduce the issue on the React demo for fullPage.js 
https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx

Comment: https://codepen.io/onfnknhz-the-sans/pen/GRPWmMr

Comment: @Alvaro Apologize for the late reply.

Comment: @Alvaro Would be really helpful if you can give any comment :)

Comment: I can't see any output on codesandbox in neither Chrome, Firefox or Safari. Make sure you have a working reproduction so we can investigate the issue.

Comment: @Alvaro Currently, our tech lead is out for vacation, so I am not sure how I can provide the reproduction, however, I found a issue that even the starter code that provided by tech lead, it does not works in Safari, but works in chrome. It consists of few tsx files. I try to copy all files to sandbox, but since there are too many node modules files, it is impossible me to copy all to codesandbox. So, I just copied main files to codesandbox and share it with you. https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-brahmagupta-slz3n5?file=/src/components/IndexWrapper.jsx

Comment: @Alvaro if that is hard you to debug the issue, is there any other way that I can send my whole starter code base to you? so you can run it and see the UI?

Comment: @Alvaro The main files are : IndexWrapper.tsx, Main.tsx, Footer.tsx, Feature.tsx, About.tsx

Comment: @Alvaro Any advice that I can get?